# google app engine to make many pages automatically

Tags: python, html, css, google-app-engine

I am building a web app with google app engine with python as well as HTML and CSS and I have a bunch of pages (around 15) that I want to make that will all somewhat different though will have a similar purpose.  Is there any way to only have a few handlers that can create a bunch of pages or do I need a different class in python for every page?

I know this question is somewhat vague without context for the pages but really any information about how to create multiple pages without coding entirely new handlers and HTML for them would be a huge help.

Comment: yes u can. what do you have right now? you need to post some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you don't need a different class for each page.

You can redirect every request to a singe script with `app.yaml`

```
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: dispatcher.app
```

Then, from `dispatcher.py` you can redirect every request to a single RequestHandler and program all your logic there, like serving a different `jinja2` template for different URLs dinamically.

The [URL Mappings documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/running#URL_Mappings) explains how to redirect multiples URLs to one RequestHandler. For example:

```
class BrowseHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):

    def get(self, category, product_id):
        # Display product with given ID in the given category.


# Map URLs like /browse/(category)/(product_id) to BrowseHandler.
application = webapp.WSGIApplication([(r'/browse/(.*)/(.*)', BrowseHandler)
                                     ],
                                     debug=True)

def main():
    run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: i dont think he is thinking of the handler definitions in app.yaml. from what i unerstand from this question is that he does not know how to handle different pages with the same requesthandler.

Comment: then why didn't you type it? [Stack Overflow doesn't know what you are thinking](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128551/183347)

Comment: @aschmid00 that's what the link to the documentation ([Running the Application](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/running)) actually explain.

Comment: @KurzedMetal you don't need to tel me... i know how to do this. :)

Answer (score 0):

It will really depend on what framework you are using (if at all), but what you are looking for is templating systems. [Here](http://www.untilnil.com/2010/08/appenginetemplates2/) is a good list of frameworks and templating systems.

Comment: Why did this answer get a downvote?  A template engine is exactly what he needs.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you're trying to do, but if you're using webapp or webapp2, you can use one handler. Check the Request parameter's url field to find out which page the user is requesting.